# Set simple boolean in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

lets say i have some data like this :

```
answers: [
{
  answerText: "please",
  small: false
},
{
  answerText: "help",
  small: true
},
{
  answerText: "me",
  small: false
}
],
```

and i want to set a boolean that´s true if there is an answer where small is true.
and i need to use it outside the loop i´m iterating over answers.

im trying arround and just dont get it, i think my nearest attempt is sth. like this

```
{% set zyx =  if 'small' in question['answers'] %}

{% set zyx =  'small' in question['answers'] %}

{% set zyx = 'small:true' in question['answers'] %}

{% set zyx = true in question['answers'] %}
```

but they all dont work as i expect

for any help thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use statements in an expression. Removing `if` will do the trick:

```
{% set zyx = 'small' in question['answers'] %}
```

---

EDIT

To check if `answer.small` is `true`, use:

```
{% set zyx = question['answers']['small'] is true %}
```

Comment: this always returns false, ithink because "in" is looking for values and not for keys? though this doesn´t get true.

Comment: tryed lots of other stuff, but no success

Comment: yes, in is looking for values. Use `'small' in question['answers']}|keys` to look for keys

Comment: but that would always return true because the key exists in every answer, but this is very close i think, i tryed {% set zyx = 'small' in question['answers']|keys is true %} but that returns exception "The test "true" does not exist"

Comment: @johnSmith I updated the answer, if a key always exists, you don't need the `in` operator

Comment: hmn still it says "The test "true" does not exist", nevertheless thanks for your engagement, also if this would work, twig would error that "Key "small" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3 ... does not exist"

Answer (score 5):

In my case,

for setting/initializing the variable value i wrote,

```
{% set status = false %}
```

and for checking

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% if status is not true %}
       // do something

       {% if item.something is true %}
          // do something

          {% set status = true %}

       {% elseif item.something is false %}
           // do something

           {% set status = false %}

       {% endif %}

    {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why do you set a variable that does not use any dynamic input?

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks for your question. I've changed my answers upon your says. Hope this will make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
{% set smallText = null %}
{% for answer in questions.answers %}
    {% if answer.small %}
        {% set smallText = answer.answerText %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if smallText is not null %}
    Small answer: {{ smallText }}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thanks, thats nice! I really head no idea how to not override it with false again, but false is not null ;) thanks